# Display surrounding HTML only if Handlebar variable is given

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, mustache

Is it possible to only display surrounding HTML around a Handlebar (or Mustache) variable if it is not empty (or not null, etc)?  For instance, given the following context and template:

```
var data = {field1:123,field2:123,field3:'',field4:123};

<dl>
    <dt>field1:</dt><dd>{{field1}}</dd>
    <dt>field2:</dt><dd>{{field2}}</dd>
    <dt>field3:</dt><dd>{{field3}}</dd>
    <dt>field4:</dt><dd>{{field4}}</dd>
</dl>
```

The following would be displayed:

field1:

123

field2:

123

field4:

123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use the if statement:

```
<dl>
    {{#if field1}}
    <dt>field1:</dt><dd>{{field1}}</dd>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if field2}}
    <dt>field2:</dt><dd>{{field2}}</dd>
    {{/if}}
    ...
</dl>
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  I just started working with handlebars today, and missed the obvious.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Rather writing if block for each field you can use the each block helper

```
<dl>
    {{#each this}}    
        {{#if this}}
            <dt>{{@key}}</dt><dd>{{this}}</dd>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</dl>
```

Here you are traversing through the object and checking if the current field is set then display the key and value otherwise move to the next field. It can help you if you have a large set of data then you don't need to write the if block again and again.Hope this helps.

Working example can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/prabhat_rai/rveap9jb/